# Sending email attachment

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I need to send a pdf file received from SFTP with an email as an attachment. I am just looking if this can be done without using custom pipeline component. Can this be done only with SMTP send port configuration. How can this be approached

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  What have you tried and what problems are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your orchestration your Out message must be modified like below. You must give your file list with pipe delimited list.
`MessageOut(SMTP.Attachments) = "C:\\temp\atachment1.pdf|C:\\temp\atachment2.pdf";`

Comment: It sounds like he is doing a messaging only solution (so no Orchestration)